# Angular 2: Implement search prediction like google

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a search box.

I want to show suggestion to complete the input inside the search box.

The REST api to match the data and return nearest suggestion is ready and working.

What I am unable to figure out is how to show the match as suggestion inside the text box in a different color. 
I found a ng2-completer component on npm but it shows suggestions in a dropdown.

I want to show the suggestion inside the drop box itself and on pressing the tab key complete the typed input using the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Typeahead from [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead). It allows some customization so you should be able to achieve what you want.